# Opening a local PDF in a new tab Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf

I have a PDF that I want to display on a button click in a new tab.. The PDF is located at file://myserver/Docs/nameofpdf.pdf. This is dynamic and will change based on a parameter given for the PDF name.

Is this possible?

I am trying:

```
window.open("file://myserver/Docs/nameofpdf.pdf");
```

However, it just opens a blank tab and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Web API and angular 2-4 together, here a nice example.

**Web Api:**

```
public HttpResponseMessage File(string fileName, string mimeType, byte[] content)
        {
            //create stream
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(content);
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileName);
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mimeType);
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength = content.Length;
            httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

            return httpResponseMessage;
        }
```

**Angular:**

```
 //get Blob data from file and open it new tab
        openPdfToNewTab(url: string) {
            Observable.create(observer => {
                let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', this.getFullPathUrl(url), true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
                xhr.responseType = 'blob';

                xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            var contentType = 'application/pdf';
                            var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], { type: contentType });
                            observer.next(blob);
                            observer.complete();
                        } else {
                            observer.error(xhr.response);
                        }
                    }
                }
                xhr.send();
            }).subscribe(data => {
                    var blob = new Blob([(<any>data)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    window.open(url);
                },
                err => {
                },
                () => { });
        };
```

**Usage:**

API:

```
[HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetMainPdf(int taskId)//, string token
        {
            //your code here
            var fileData = GetFile(); //some code here
            // return file
            return File($"{fileData.FileName}", fileData.MimeType, fileData.Content);
        }
```

Angular:

```
//you can call this function on click
getMainPdf() {
        return this.openPdfToNewTab(YOUR-API-URL); //url for download file
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with triple slashes:
`window.open("file:///myserver/Docs/nameofpdf.pdf");`
Or remove the `file` protocol.

Assuming this application runs locally only.